# Is There A Way To Pull Information From External Websites Into P5.js

Tags: p5.js, external-data-access

so what I want to do is to pull information from certain sites.

For example, let's say I want to make a weather tracking site that sources information from another site, but I want the information to be raw data that I can put into variables, not screenshots or redirect links. I wanted to know if JS is required for this, or do I also have to use HTML?

What I want is there to be a simple way to pull information from a site like https://weather.com/, and store it into a variable so that I can manage it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pull information from arbitrary websites. However, you can use an API that uses HTTP and JSON, text, or XML data if you can find one that meets your needs (note: it must also support cross origin requests). For example, [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/api) is one I’ve seen used with p5.js. Additionally p5.js has the [`loadJSON()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON) function which can make it easier to get data from an API so long as it supports GET and does not require custom headers. For more advanced APIs you may want to look for a library that supports it or you may have to use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).